# Importar/incuir outros arquivos - go (golang)

Tags: arquivo, importação, golang

estou estudando go (golang) e tenho uma dúvida em relação a importação de arquivos, a dúvida é sobre algo "elementar" mas não consegui achar nada especificamente sobre isso.

Tenho um pacote (**test**) disposto dessa forma:

```
test -> main.go
     -> test.go
```

Gostaria de importar o **test.go** dentro de **main.go**?

```
//em javascript seria algo assim:
//main.go
require('./test.go')
```

Como fazer o mesmo em go?

Answer (score 1):

Golang usa um sistema de pacotes, então não há como você importar "um único arquivo".

Não sei qual a sua situação ai exatamente, mas se ambos arquivos pertencerem ao mesmo pacote, então não há necessidade de importar nada, é como se eles fossem um único grande arquivo. Caso eles estejam em pacotes separados, você pode importar o pacote.

```
import "meupacote"
```

ou

```
import (
    "umpacote"
    "outropacote"
)
```

Lembrando que a declaração do import deve vir logo após o nome do seu pacote.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, world.\n")
}
```

Uma vez importado, todos os identificadores exportados (primeira letra maiúscula) do pacote ficam disponíveis para serem usados.

Recomendo usar a palavra `test` com cuidado, afinal, ela tem significado especial durante a compilação e execução de testes.

Comment: No youtube tem bastante material explicando sobre pacotes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9hPwNx_UPI

Answer (score 0):

como ele ta dentro do diretorio main, não é necessário importa, neste caso é só chamar as funções e variáveis que estão dentro do arquivo test.go

caso seu arquivo estivesse entre ou pacote como por exemplo:

-> principal -> main.go 
             -> exemplo/-> exemplo.go

neste caso você teria que importar em seu arquivo main.go:

```
package main
import "principal/exemplo"
import "fmt"

func main(){
   fmt.Println(exemplo("Olá, Exemplo!"))
}
```